# Unable to load xib file

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to use a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Setup:
Xcode 7.1, Swift, running in Emulator
Steps:
1. Created a new "Cocoa Touch Class"(CMD+N) with Subclass of `UITableViewCell` 
2. Also create XIB file, when creating the swift file.
3. Now I would like to load the XIB file into a TableViewController

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let yourNibName = UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(yourNibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "test") // << EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
...
```

I get: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Info: 
1. I can see in the debug area: that yourNibName has a memory address but all other properties is 0x0. Therefore the XIB must not be loaded?
2. I can see it is a member in the Inspector: Target Membership
3. It is in "Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources"
4. I do Product Clean every each thing I am trying.
But why?

Comment: Did you add your Nib to your project's target?

Comment: Yes: I can see it is a member in the Inspector: Target Membership.

Comment: Did you add your "MyTableViewCell" identifier to the prototype cell?

Comment: In the Attribute Inspector I have set; identifier to "test". Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

try this

your top should look like this

```
class myTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

view did load func like this:

```
  tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "test")
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
```

and this func like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("test", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        tableView.rowHeight = 470
        tableView.allowsSelection = false

        return cell
    }
```

If it does not work let me know..

Comment: in MyTableViewCell.xib your cell identifier should be "test" so check if it is the same and you should also check if there is no spelling mistake in "MyTableViewCell"

Comment: Thanks Ondra, I created the ViewController from code and was missing the self.view itself :-/

Comment: Yes, you and others was/is on the right track :-) See my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One could only wish for better error messages in Xcode. That said I was creating a TableViewController from code, and was missing the view itself.

```
self.tableView = UITableView(frame:self.view.frame)
```

And ofcource you can not do anything with the view being nil, and that includes trying to                 `tableView.registerNib`